# SQL Command Error

Tags: c#, mysql, syntax-error

here is the story :

Im trying to insert some data form the form to my data base but some thing wrong with the syntax "Vs Say so" but i can't find the mistake and some one help ?

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=ltdb;UID=root;Password=1234;port=3306");
try
{
    string command = "(INSERT INTO invoice companyName,rate,svatNo,tinNo,line1,line2,city)VALUES('" + this.txtname.Text + "','" + this.txtrate.Text + "','" + this.txtsvatno.Text + "','" + this.txttinno.Text + "','" + txtadline1.Text + "','" + txtadline2.Text + "','" + txtcity.Text + "');";
    conn.Open();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(command, conn);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Saved !");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Use parameters.  Your code is open to SQL injection.

Comment: The bracket must be after invoice. Not before insert

Comment: Please add the VS error to your description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your

```
string command = "(INSERT INTO invoice companyName,rate,svatNo,tinNo,line1,line2,city)VALUES('" + this.txtname.Text + "','" + this.txtrate.Text + "','" + this.txtsvatno.Text + "','" + this.txttinno.Text + "','" + txtadline1.Text + "','" + txtadline2.Text + "','" + txtcity.Text + "');";
```

To

```
string command = "INSERT INTO invoice (companyName,rate,svatNo,tinNo,line1,line2,city) VALUES (@name,@rate,@vatno,@tinno,@adline1,@adline2,@city)";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("name",txtname.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("rate",txtrate.Text);
....
```

*Edit: For more info, google "c# parameterized sql"

Answer (score 1):

`INSERT INTO invoice companyName, ...` missing opening brace, correct is

```
INSERT INTO invoice(column1, column2, ...) VALUES (@Columns1, @columns2, ...)
```

Coming to point 2: you're [open for sql-injection](https://xkcd.com/327/). Use parameterized queries.

Answer (score 0):

You put Wrong bracket

```
INSERT INTO invoice (companyName,rate,svatNo,tinNo,line1,line2,city) VALUES ('" + this.txtname.Text + "','" + this.txtrate.Text + "','" + this.txtsvatno.Text + "','" + this.txttinno.Text + "','" + txtadline1.Text + "','" + txtadline2.Text + "','" + txtcity.Text + "');
```